# What is the definition of load disturbance

Tags: control-system

I am studying the Conputers and Control. My teacher meationed "load disturbances" in his PowerPoint Silde. I have searched on the Internet about the definition. However, I did not find any clue. So could you please explain this word to me?

Comment: What is the context ? Is it related to regulated voltage supplies ? Is it related to AC power transmission and distribution ? Where did you hear about this term ? Please use the [edit] link below the question to addmore details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is tagged "control-system" I will assume that this is the context. In this context, "load" means the process or some aspect of the process that is being controlled. A "disturbance" is something that influences the system in a way that would cause a change in the parameter that is being controlled.

For example, assume that a conveyor is moving products from a warehouse to a truck loading system. The conveyor speed is controlled by a control system. Most of the time, items are placed on the conveyor at a steady rate, the motor uses a certain amount of power and runs at a steady speed. If a particularly heavy item is placed on the conveyor, that might be considered a "load disturbance" and the speed might drop as a result.

A heating system might experience a load disturbance if someone opens a door on a cold day. A city water supply system might experience a load disturbance if the fire department opens several hydrants to fight a fire.

Control systems and process equipment are generally designed to cope with load disturbances, but some process parameters may deviate from expected values for a short time or even fro the duration of the disturbance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your explaination is so clear and helpful!!